# If $f(a) < f(p)$ and $f(p) > f(b)$ then there is a $d$ such that $f'(d)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing

If $f: [a,b] → R$ is a continuous function which is differentiable on $(a,b)$,

And if $f(a) < f(p)$ and $f(p) > f(b)$ for some $p ∈ (a, b)$. Show that there exists
$d ∈ (a, b)$ such that $f'(d) = 0$

I know I need to use Rolle's Theorem and the intermediate value theorem to do this, however I am unsure where to start with this. I think I understand it graphically but I am not sure how to put this into a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f(a)<f(b)$. Then $f(a)<f(b)<f(p)$, such that by the Intermediate Value Thereom, there is an $x\in(a,p)$ such that $f(x)=f(b)$. Thus we have $f(x)=f(b)$ and by Rolle's Theorem there is a $d\in(x,b)$ such that $f'(d)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need Rolle's theorem.

$f$ is continuous on the compact interval $[a,b]$, and therefore 
attains its maximum value at some point $d$ in the interval.
From the conditions $f(a) < f(p)$ and $f(p) > f(b)$ it follows 
that the maximum is not attained at the boundary, so $d \in (a, b)$
and then $f'(d) = 0$.